# Could not load type "Website.TridionCMS.ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver' from assembly 'ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver

Tags: 2013, publishing, tom.net, custom-resolver

I've written a custom resolver to block publish transactions from certain publications by referring through below blog [https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/childpublicationsonlyresolver.aspx.](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/childpublicationsonlyresolver.aspx)

Our deployment server don't have .NET SDK, so no GACutil.

So, I created a setup project and installed MSIL to register the DLL in the GA_MSIL. DLL is present in the GAC MSIL.

When i publish any item from the CMS, it throws following error.

```
Could not load type '***' from assembly 'ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26c2d68fe54df544'.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetResolversFromConfiguration(IEnumerable`1 itemTypes)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.ResolveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, ResolveInstruction instruction, IEnumerable`1 contexts)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.ResolveItem(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

When i copy the DLL manually to the GAC_MSIL, publishing works fine.

Please provide your suggestions and inputs!

Comment: UnreadableQuestionException ;-)

Comment: i think this is generic .net question, isn't it? you wanted to copy dll in GAC. when you manually copy paste, do it replace the existing or you see multiple entries in GAC viewer.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually multiple GAC_MSIL directories

1. **%windir%\assembly\GAC_MSIL** - for .net framework 2.0 and 3.5 or less than 4.0
2. **%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL** - For net framwork 4+

make sure you putting in the correct one.

Comment: Registered the dll using MSIL and using .net framework 4+ and it is located in the %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Comment: so what's exactly issue now?

Comment: when try to publish any items from CMS Could not load type 'TridionCMS.ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver' from assembly 'ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26c2d68fe54df544'.

Comment: few points to check. 1) check TridionCMS.ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver class exist , try recompile & put again 2) check , its if another version of assembly at some location and that is getting loaded instead of latest version, change the version to check.

Comment: when copy paste the dll in the GAC_MSIL it is not replacing seeing mulitple entries

Comment: so that may be problem. Dll is stored on 4 parameters, name, version culture and Public key token. if any of this is different, new entry will be created. Remove all dlls from GAC first then put your latest DLL. if required also update references.